# What is the prefered way of updating all software in a Fedora installation?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, upgrade

When I install some system, I usually look for a bulk update method, one that will update my recently-installed software.

For example, in Debian, that would be changing the `sources.list` to point to what I want, and executing `# apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Is there an equivalent to this in Fedora (18)? Is there a GUI upgrade manager that I am missing?

A message in Gnome popped up that my system requires important updates. I dismissed it, as the only option it had presented me with was "Install updates", and I wasn't quite sure what would that do.

Now, the message has disappeared, and I cannot find it, not any software it might have been connected with.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The `yum update` answer is my preferred mode. But, there is a GUI software manager, if you'd like to use it. In Gnome 3, go to activities and do a search for "software update" (or find it in your list of applications). That will do the same for you, too.

Comment: I would suggest changing title of this question so that it better matched the question which is being concerned specifically with upgrading **from one release to another**. Upgrading *all software* could mean different things thus it's not aligned well with the question.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I'm not talking about release upgrades, `dist-upgrade` can be use at any time for a complete upgrade...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Before Fedora 17

None of the Red Hat distros prior to Fedora 17 included the ability to do dist-upgrades as you've asked. This had been a long discussed option on many peoples' wish list but had never been implemented.

*But before we start a clarification...*

> According to the [Upgrading topic in the wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading), there was a method
>   where you could put a DVD in your system for the next version of
>   Fedora, and [Anaconda](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda) would attempt to upgrade your system. Having
>   tried this method on numerous occasions I would not consider this to
>   be on par with the `dist-upgrade` available in the Debian/Ubuntu
>   distros which actually worked very well.
>
> Additionally having maintained RHEL, Fedora & CentOS systems for over the past decade, I would never even consider using this method for anything. It simply did not work.

So typically people would do one of the following:

#### Rawhide

Use the [Rawhide release](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/Rawhide?rd=Rawhide), which is the bleeding edge version, similar to how Sid is in Debian. Rawhide offers rolling releases in the sense that it always has the latest versions of packages, but it's by no means meant to be used as a day to day distro, it's really meant only for testing.

#### Stay with a single release

Just live with this fact and stay up to date as long as the distro stayed around, using `yum`. You can use `yum` to both apply any pending updates and/or update a single package. Additionally, `yum` can be used to install new packages too.

Apply all pending updates (assumes yes to all prompts):

```
sudo yum -y update
```

Update a single package:

```
sudo yum -y update apache\*
```

Install a new package:

```
sudo yum -y install apache\*
```

#### Software Update Applet

If you want to perform updates using a GUI you can use the software updater tool that shows up in your taskbar. This tool essentially does the same thing as the `yum -y update` above, and can be run on demand using the following command:

```
gpk-update-viewer
```

#### Re-install

As a new version comes out, you'd manually do a fresh install and take care to copy any data and configurations forward to the new system.

#### PreUpgrade

Make use of [PreUpgrade](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_PreUpgrade?rd=PreUpgrade) tool. This tool essentially just collected your setups and the names of the packages you installed and would assist you in applying them to a new installation. See [@JoelDavis' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75699/7453) for this technique as well.

**NOTE:** This is no longer an option starting with Fedora 18 though so you've been warned.

### Fedora 17 and after

Beginning with 17 you can now do rolling releases.

#### FedUp

New in Fedora 17/18 is a tool called [FedUp (FEDora UPgrader)](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp) which purports to do "dist-upgrades" similar to Debian/Ubuntu distros.

> FedUp (FEDora UPgrader) is the name of a new system for upgrading
>   Fedora installs in Fedora 18 and above releases. It replaces all of
>   the currently recommended upgrade methods (PreUpgrade and DVD) that
>   have been used in previous Fedora releases. Anaconda, the Fedora
>   installer does have not any in-built upgrade functionality in Fedora
>   18 or above releases. It has been completely delegated to Fedup.
>
> Currently, FedUp is capable of upgrading Fedora 17 installs to Fedora
>   18 using a networked repository, similar to how PreUpgrade worked.
>   More methods for upgrade are currently planned and this page will be
>   updated as those features are completed.

### Rolling Releases vs. Versioned Releases

The OP asked a follow-up question where he wanted me to elaborate on the following phrase:

> "Beginning with 17 you can now do rolling releases."

When I made that comment I meant one thing and the phrase "rolling releases" really means something else. When I wrote that I meant "rolling release" to mean that you could now roll from one point release of Fedora (say 17) to version 18. Most distros such as Debian & Ubuntu provide this facility now.

However in looking up the description of what ["rolling releases" actually means on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release), I'm now more educated on the subject.

*excerpt from wikipedia*

> ... a rolling release or rolling update development model refers to a
>   continually developing software system; this is instead of a standard
>   release development model which uses software versions that must be
>   reinstalled over the previous version. Rolling software, instead, is
>   continually updated, in contrast to standard release software which is
>   upgraded between versions. ...

So from a purists standpoint, Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, are not "rolling releases". They are point standard released software that provide tools to assist in the upgrading from one point release to another.

*The OP also asked the following question*

> Debian is only "kind of" rolling release if you use Sid. Rolling
>   release = no versions, packages are just dumped into the distro from
>   the upstream ASAP, right? So Debian is the complete opposite of a
>   rolling release, Ubuntu as well. Fedora Rawhide is also kind-of a
>   rolling release, but I already knew that (and don't want to use it, if
>   that's what you were referring to).

Just so that it's clear to any future readers. Even the development branches of Debian (aka. Sid) and Fedora (aka. Rawhide) are not "rolling releases". Sure you can use them as such but they are merely a development "area" where new packages of software that *may* be incorporated into a future release can be presented to the community in a centralized way.

The level of testing that would go into a package being placed in one of these branches is less stringent than say when a package shows up as an update in a true "rolling release" distro such as ArchLinux (would be my expectation).

Here's the section of the wikipedia page that covers the use of development branches for standard release distros:

> The distinction between rolling release software distributions and
>   development branches of standard release software distributions is
>   often overlooked by users inexperienced with rolling distributions.
>   This can lead to confused comments, such as: "distro-X is a rolling
>   distribution if you use its development branch" — where distro-X is a
>   standard release distribution. Even in rare cases where the
>   development branch is a rolling (versus the more common cyclical)
>   development branch, this does not make the distribution rolling.
>   Unlike standard release distributions, rolling release distributions
>   do not have development branches.

Comment: Wrong... you have always been able to update everything in one go. You **can not** upgrade that way, e.g. from Fedora 17 to 18. For that [a bit more dancing](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading) is required, but it is quite painless nowadays.

Comment: @vonbrand, what aspect of the answer is wrong. Please elaborate. Are you referring to using the DVD and letting anaconda update your exising system to the version on the DVD? Having tried this method on numerous occasions I would not consider that a "method" compared to the dist-upgrade which actually works.

Comment: @vonbrand, I've updated the answer to include the Anaconda DVD installer upgrade.

Comment: "Beginning with 17 you can now do rolling releases." - would you care providing an explanation?

Comment: @Yannbane - are you asking what "rolling releases" are or are you asking how do you do them?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I'm wondering how do you get a rolling-release Fedora. The only distro I know about that does it is Archlinux...

Comment: @Yannbane - Debian & Ubuntu are rolling releases as well. Most of the distros can do this. Did you read the `FedUp` page that I provided the link to? It has all the details for upgrading your Fedora 17 system to 18 and so forth.

Comment: Debian is only "kind of" rolling release if you use Sid. Rolling release = no versions, packages are just dumped into the distro from the upstream ASAP, right? So Debian is the complete opposite of a rolling release, Ubuntu as well. Fedora Rawhide is also kind-of a rolling release, but I already knew that (and don't want to use it, if that's what you were referring to).

Comment: @Yannbane - see my updates to the answer. Hopefully that clears things up, lmk if you need additional points followed up.

Comment: Yeah, great, it's clear now.

Comment: If `gpk-update-viewer` is not installed, `dnf install gnome-packagekit-updater`. (Alternative: `apper`)

Answer (score 6):

You can use

`yum update` (to upgrade all packages )

and

`yum update <packageName>` (to update individual installed packages)

This works on a **Fedora** and/or **CentOS** and/or **Redhat EL** systems

You can also use

`yum install <packagename>` or `yum install <RPM Name or web path>` (to install packages on these systems as well)

There is an application called Software Updater that provides a GUI but `yum` is actually very efficient and pretty intuitive.

If you have any questions about what switches you can run with yum you can use 
`yum --help`

Comment: if you use `dnf install widget` it may not update it if it's already installed... but `dnf update widget` will update it. It seems there is some variation on this between package managers such as apt, pkg, npm and pip.

Answer (score 4):

Although I found no online page that would describe this, the `# apt-get 
upgrade` alternative on Fedora seems to be `# yum update`.

From the man pages of yum:

> update --- If  run without any packages, update will update every
>   currently
>                 installed package.  If one or more packages or package globs are
>                 specified,  Yum  will  only  update  the listed packages.  While
>                 updating packages, yum will ensure  that  all  dependencies  are
>                 satisfied.  (See  Specifying package names for more information)
>                 If the packages or globs specified match to packages  which  are
>                 not  currently  installed  then  update  will  not install them.
>                 update operates on groups, files, provides  and  filelists  just
>                 like the "install" command.

Comment: It is, but when `yum` or `dnf` upgrade are interrupted they are particularly awkward to recover and do not provide much help.  It turns out this causes problems if the upgrade crashes the GUI (and you ran the command from inside the GUI).  So you are supposed to use different methods, which nowadays include `pkcon update`.  https://lwn.net/Articles/702629/

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when going to a new version, I'll generally do a full re-install of the system.  I have found updating packages in place to be quite problematic and the amount of time spent in debugging the problems there are more complex than doing a reinstall.

Comment: I'd like to hear more about this, please. Not having to reinstall when doing upgrades is something I liked a lot with Debian...

Comment: Personally, I have not found that RH/Fedora upgrades are problematic and being burnt once have done reinstalls of the new systems instead of messing around with major version updates.  Minor version updates have been successful however.  Debian might be different.

Comment: Never seen any problem with my Fedora updates since Fedora 14 or so. The mechanism has changed significatly lately, though. But my latest Fedora 16 --> 17 --> 18 went without a hitch, mostly unattended over the 'net.

Comment: I can't wait for the 20th release to see for myself... Or I could just download 18 and upgrade to 19 but I really don't want to bother with that.