# Why distros don't have a unique version which continously provide updates?

Tags: distributions

I don't see the point why distros, instead of building new versions, don't have a unique version, which continously provide upgrades for the linux kernel, desktop environment, software packages, etc. Everything seems to be upgreadable in a distro version to convert it in the following version. Clearly I am missing something.

For instance, new distros' versions release notes feature new software versions, like gcc or gnome, but they could have been upgraded in a previous version, so what is the point?

Comment: [How do rolling releases work ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97291/22142)

Comment: Ah! Didn't know of their existence. So my question turns out to be: what are the disadvantages of rolling releases distros? I'll google it.. thx!

Comment: I cover this a bit in this Q&A: [What is the prefered way of updating all software in a Fedora installation?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75687/what-is-the-prefered-way-of-updating-all-software-in-a-fedora-installation/75715#75715)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, sir, are looking for [Arch Linux.](https://www.archlinux.org/) You do have to run `pacman -Syu` about once or twice a week to stay current, but after that, you've got the latest versions of everything.

As far as disadvantages, occasionally something big and complex will make a clean break with the past, and you'll have to do some weird extra work. Changing from PostgreSQL v8 to v9 comes to mind, as does changing to `systemd`. There's just no "typical" with that kind of thing. The `pacman` package manager takes care of upgrades and packages that get replaced by other packages, things like that.

Comment: Not the best answer I was hoping, but helped me to understand what I was not understanding, so thanks